# Best way to signal no longer used (lost) key

Tags: pgp, public-key, openpgp

I have an old PGP key for which I don't have the secret anymore, nor the revocation certificate, and when I created the key I did it without expiration date.

So I know, I have to move on, and so I did. I created a new key. Now I would like to somehow show in the keyservers that the key that the old key should not be used. I've read that to that purpose there are several approaches:

1. Create a key with a UID that warns about the deprecation and sign an old key with that.
2. Designate revoke even without designated revoker grants on the old key to the new one.
3. Sign the old key with the new one and then revoke the signature.

Which one is the most correct course of action to take, if any, and how do I do it? I wanted to do #2 but it gives me an error that no revocation key was found, I guess perhaps because I am not a designated revoker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a situation without a really good solution.

> 1. Create a key with a UID that warns about the deprecation and sign an old key with that.

This results in visibility at the wrong end: anybody just having the old key (or finding it first) will not get any clue the old key is (might be) superseded.

On the other hand, this information is always displayed prominently for users of your correct key. And it reads a little bit as "Hey you there, I lost control over my old key, don't use it any more, I'll do better next time."

> 2. Designate revoke even without designated revoker grants on the old key to the new one.

Due to the missing revoker grants, the revocation will not be valid. Depending on the software used, at least some message is displayed to the user informing him something's fishy.

In my opinion, the best you can do, anyway. I'm sure I once did exactly that for testing purpose -- but I can't reproduce it any more. Either some safeguards have been added to GnuPG, I hit some bug in the past or something else went wrong. You might be able to hack GnuPG's source code or use some other implementation to perform this operation without this safeguard, though.

> 3. Sign the old key with the new one and then revoke the signature.

Again, this will not really revoke the key, but only carry some information for the user to interpret. This will not be visible to most users when searching for keys, but you can even add a text message. Semantically, you do not revoke the key but the user ID (so repeat for all user IDs, if you had multiple).

---

Generally, all of those do not really revoke your key. Make sure your new key gets integrated well in the web of trust: ask your friends and workmates for signatures, go to key signing parties. Hope other will use your new key, if it has deeper integration in the web of trust and is newer.

And pre-create a revocation certificate. Put it in safe places where you will never lose it. Hand it over to a friend or other trusted person. He will only be able to revoke your key, but not do anything else with it.